# How to implement Caliburn.Micro style MVVM in Angular2

Tags: .net, wpf, angular, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have experience with `WPF` and `MVVM` with `Caliburn.Micro` and trying to implement a simple example in Angular2.

I had in WPF:

1. `View`: completely separated from business logic, only contains code for the view
2. `ViewModel`: it contains the business logic
3. `Commands`: like services in `Angular2`

I want to implement this:

> After clicking on the button, send the text from the `TextBox` to the server and clear the `TextBox`. Disable the button if the `TextBox` is empty.

I implemented this in `WPF` like this:

This is my View:

```
<TextBox Name="Message" /> <!-- Binding created by Caliburn.Micro -->
<Button Name="Save" /> <!-- Binding created by Caliburn.Micro -->
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
public string Message { get; set { // ... NotifyPropertyChanged ... } }

public bool CanSave 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Message);
    }
}

public void Save
{
     var cmd = new SaveCommand(Message);
     cmd.Run();
     Message = null;
}
```

This is the command:

```
public class SaveCommand 
{ 
     public void Run()
     {
          // ...
     }
}
```

As you see I didn't had to write `Click` handlers, create binding etc. It was nicely handled by `Caliburn`. No clutter, it's just very simple and easily extendable. `Save` and `CanSave` is nicely separated too. I do not have to worry about `CanSave` in the `Save` method.

I could reuse the `Command`, reuse the `ViewModel` and even the `View`. I could create new `ViewModels` by inheriting from existing `ViewModels`. I could use the `View` with different `ViewModels` and vice versa.

How can I achieve similar functionality in `Angular2`? Should I put my business logic into a `Component`? The `ViewModel` is somehow missing from Angular2...?

Comment: This might help you to get some idea https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-form-builder-and-validation-management

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I am looking for. I know how to do this with a simple `Component`, but that's not enough :)

Comment: @David, you really want to look at Aurelia then its very similar to CM since Rob created Caliburn, and some of the same principles are in place with http://aurelia.io/